# Call to a function using python gives not defined error

Tags: python

I need to assign a NOTE to a PORTFOLIO.
I have written the code in Python to login to LendingClub and that works fine (I am able to get the balance).
When I call the assign_to_portfolio() function I get an error "NameError: name 'assign_to_portfolio' is not defined"

But i have run the command "import lendingclub" and assign_to_portfolio() is part of the **init**.py as in [https://github.com/jgillick/LendingClub/blob/master/lendingclub/**init**.py](https://github.com/jgillick/LendingClub/blob/master/lendingclub/__init__.py).
what am I doing wrong?

```
lc_InvestorId = "xxxxx"
lc_apikey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
url = "https://api.lendingclub.com/api/investor/v1/accounts/" + lc_InvestorId + "/availablecash"

import requests
import argparse
import sys
import glob
from lendingclub import LendingClub
import lendingclub


payload = ""
headers = {
    'ContentType': "application/json",
    'Accept': "application/json",
    'Authorization': lc_apikey,
    'X-LC-Application-Key': "null"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)

assign_to_portfolio()
```

Comment: I think you need something like `lendingclub.assign_to_portfolio()` since that function is defined there, not in your own file.

Comment: Thanks eyllanesc . I now get error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'assign_to_portfolio'

Comment: `assign_to_portfolio` is an instance method of the `LendingClub` class; you need an instance of that class to call the method. Please read through a basic Python tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `assign_to_portfolio()` must be called on your instance of `LendingClub`

From what I understand reading the README and the docstring of the LendignClub class:

You "connect" to your account with email and password by passing them as parameters to `LendingClub` and then calling `.authenticate()` or inserting them in the console on calling `.authenticate()` on a default instance of `LendingClub`. Then, you can, with the `.authenticate()`ed instance, perform actions.

To get everything to work as intended, I suggest you follow the examples in the [README](https://github.com/jgillick/LendingClub/blob/master/README.rst) (--do they provide demo accounts?) and then add what exactly you want.

After reading the README, I must say that I understand the code in the question less, are you sure you're not over-complicating things? (Like mixing emulating the browser with using the API with using the simple python package)

Comment: Ok thanks user24343. Yes i am able to login using the original code (not my API key methord), but how do I pass the login and password as variables (instead of having to type them in every time). I believe I will need to pass them to the script \site-packages\lendingclub\__init__.py

Comment: @hdsouza yes, if you want to have them in the code, pass them as arguments when creating your ``LendignClub`` instance. ``lc = lendingclub.LendingClud(email='test@example.com', password='secret')``. You can then call ``lc.assign_to_portfolio(name, loan_id, order_id)``

Comment: Thanks user24343!!!!! That worked great.  It took me 3 months to get to this along with hiring a Python developer who had no clue what he was doing. U da man